# Copy Table Data To Another Table In The Same Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have a table name: `KTS` & Another Table Name `KTS1` ,and both of them in the same `DATABASE` name `HR` ,I want to move the data table from `KTS` to `KTS1`.

Comment: Read some of this... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: can you elaborate on this `I want to move the data table from KTS TO KTS1`,are you looking for rename or moving entire data

Comment: no, i want the same columns data

Answer (score 2):

Think you are looking to copy data from one table to another. If yes, then you can use `insert into .. select from` construct like below (assuming both table structure is exactly same, else you will have to manually specify the column names)

```
insert into kts1
select * from kts;
```

Comment: This also assumes no `IDENTITY` column (and how to fix that would depend on what outcome the OP is looking for)